# Missing attribute error in Jobs#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

A little bit of background: I recently got a new job as a Rails developer which is all fine and dandy (I have a Rails background), but I am running into a problem and I cannot figure it out. The job I took involved taking over a project someone else at the company started but never finished. So I have a unfinished CRM application in my lap, and need the help of more experienced developers to point me in the right direction.

When I try to create a new job, I get an error "**ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in Jobs#new**", followed by "**can't write unknown attribute `opportunity_id**'".

The error from the terminal is:

```
Started GET "/jobs/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-17 10:07:44 -0700
Processing by JobsController#new as HTML
  Rendered jobs/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms

ActionView::Template::Error (can't write unknown attribute `opportunity_id'):
    1: <% @job[:opportunity_id] = params[:opportunity_id] %>
    2: <% title "New #{@job.opportunity.name} Job"%>
    3:
    4: <%
  app/views/jobs/new.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_jobs_new_html_erb__443350051_40007592'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (34.0ms)
```

The error comes from line 1 which is:

```
<% @job[:opportunity_id] = params[:opportunity_id] %>
```

**UPDATED**: Added job model and job controller, along with the view and jobs table from shcema.rb file.

**Job Model:**

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :file1, AttachmentUploader
  belongs_to :cost_proposal
  has_many :opportunities
end
```

**Job Controller:**

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  skip_load_and_authorize_resource
  # GET /jobs
  # GET /jobs.json
  def index
    @jobs = Job.all
  end

  # GET /jobs/1
  # GET /jobs/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /jobs/new
  def new
  end

  # GET /jobs/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /jobs
  # POST /jobs.json
  def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.save
        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /jobs/1
  # PATCH/PUT /jobs/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.update(job_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /jobs/1
  # DELETE /jobs/1.json
  def destroy
    @job.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to jobs_url, notice: 'Job was successfully deleted.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_job
      @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def job_params
      params.require(:job).permit(:opportunity_id, :number, :name, :flight_date, :flight_sub, :camera, :roll, :map_type, :plan_only, :lab_only, :est_hrs_model, :due_date, :edge_job_id, :custom_trans, :comp_inhouse, :delivered_date, :done, :control_in, :control_status, :at_date, :control_results, :control_check, :scan_staff, :scan_date, :scan_check, :comp_staff, :comp_date, :comp_check, :comp_sub, :comp_sub_due_date, :comp_sub_rec, :img_staff, :img_date, :img_check, :edit_staff, :edit_date, :edit_check, :notes, :file1, :file2, :file3, :file4, :file5, :add_files)
    end
end
```

**Jobs table from schema.rb:**

```
  create_table "jobs", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "cost_proposal_id"
    t.string   "number"
    t.string   "name"
    t.date     "flight_date"
    t.string   "flight_sub"
    t.string   "camera"
    t.string   "roll"
    t.string   "map_type"
    t.integer  "plan_only"
    t.integer  "lab_only"
    t.integer  "est_hrs_model"
    t.date     "due_date"
    t.integer  "edge_job_id"
    t.integer  "custom_trans"
    t.integer  "comp_inhouse"
    t.date     "delivered_date"
    t.integer  "done"
    t.date     "control_in"
    t.string   "control_status"
    t.date     "at_date"
    t.string   "control_results"
    t.integer  "control_check"
    t.string   "scan_staff"
    t.date     "scan_date"
    t.integer  "scan_check"
    t.string   "comp_staff"
    t.date     "comp_date"
    t.integer  "comp_check"
    t.string   "comp_sub"
    t.date     "comp_sub_due_date"
    t.integer  "comp_sub_rec"
    t.string   "img_staff"
    t.date     "img_date"
    t.integer  "img_check"
    t.string   "edit_staff"
    t.date     "edit_date"
    t.integer  "edit_check"
    t.text     "notes"
    t.string   "file1"
    t.string   "file2"
    t.string   "file3"
    t.string   "file4"
    t.string   "file5"
    t.string   "add_files"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "flown"
    t.integer  "cust_trans"
    t.integer  "delivered"
    t.string   "at_staff"
    t.integer  "at_check"
  end
```

**Opportunities table from schema.rb:**

```
  create_table "opportunities", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "employee_id"
    t.integer  "emp2_id"
    t.integer  "emp3_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "prop_date"
    t.integer  "opp_status_id"
    t.string   "delay"
    t.date     "con_signed"
    t.integer  "quote_won_id"
    t.float    "total_cost"
    t.date     "exp_close"
    t.integer  "pri_comp_id"
    t.text     "notes"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "lost"
    t.string   "won"
    t.string   "location"
    t.integer  "pm_id"
  end
```

**Jobs new view (where error is occuring):**

```
<% @job[:opportunity_id] = params[:opportunity_id] %>
<% title "New #{@job.opportunity.name} Job"%>

<% 
@job[:name] = @job.opportunity.name 
@pm = @job.opportunity.pm_id


%>

<br><br>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

If you need more files from the project, let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `params` takes a user input, most likely you can see it from the url. You should see somethings like `https://www.site_name.com/index.html?opportunity_id=4` when the query is submitted. It is possible the attribute is named differently, check and see if there is something in the url once you submit.

Comment: The URL is 'localhost:3000/jobs/new', nothing with 'opportunity_id=4'

Comment: Check your logger and see what params are being passed in your request from the form. Then make sure that attribute being passed matches the attributes for the Job class. 

In order to keep debugging you can also grab the params being passed from the form and use them to create a Job object from within the console.

Comment: So in the new job view the param being passed is 'opportunity_id'. When looking at the Job class, the following is there: class Job < ActiveRecord::Base mount_uploader :file1, AttachmentUploader belongs_to :cost_proposal. If I added has_many :opportunity_id would that do the trick?

Comment: This is an attribute error on the model. It may be a silly question, but better to cover your bases: are you certain there's an opportunity_id on the model? in your rails console do `Job.new` and look at the attributes in the output and verify that opportunity_id is actually an attribute.

Comment: @jaydel my job model includes this: class Job < ActiveRecord::Base (next line) mount_uploader :file1, AttachmentUploader (next line) belongs_to :cost_proposal (next line) end. In a previous comment I mentioned adding has_many :opportunity_id, or would it be has_many :opportunities? Thanks in advance

Comment: @jaydel after running Job.new in the console, there is no opportunity_id listed. I assume adding this attribute will fix the problem? If so, can I add it from the console? Thanks.

Comment: You should check the database first to see if that column is in there. if not, add it via a migration. If it is there, then there's probably something amiss with your associations. If you find it's in the db already, add your models (or perhaps the relevant parts--associations, etc) to the question.

Comment: @kmaune Just saw your question. The proper way to do it would be `has_many :opportunities`  Rails will figure out the rest for you.

Comment: @jaydel After doing what you have suggested, I got another error that states undefined 'method `[]=' for nil:NilClass'. I am updating the question to include my job model and job controller. Thanks again for taking the time to help, this is really frustrating me.

Comment: @kmaune I hate to do this to you, but can you add the schema.rb content for the opportunities table, please?

Comment: @jaydel Absolutely. Question is updated :) thanks so much

Comment: @kmaune I created an answer that I hope addresses your concern. At the very least it will give us a place to discuss it further without losing track in comments (moderators can and do often go through and trim out comments--they are ephemeral by nature here)

Answer (score 1):

An `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError` is raised when you try to set an attribute on a model which does not exist. Remember that ActiveRecord "automagically" creates setters and getters by reading the schema from the database.

The most common reasons are:

- typo (for example the db column is named `oportunity‌​_id`)
- the migration which adds the column to the schema has not been run
- there is no migration to add the column

Also assigning attributes to the model in the view is a pretty bad code smell. Do it in the controller instead:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def new
    @job = Job.new do |j|
      if params[:opportunity_id].present?
        j.opportunity_id = params[:opportunity_id]
      end
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Good stuff. It also could be that the association itself is missing or incorrectly defined.

Comment: I tried this, but received an error stating something relating to .empty?. I apologize but I can't remember exactly what it said.

Comment: Ah you're right there I forgot that `.empty?` will raise an error on nil. Edited to use `.present?` instead.

Comment: I will give that a shot, thank you for taking the time to help :)

Comment: @max I gave that a shot and got a 'can't write unknown attribute `opportunity_id'' error. What is throwing me off is when I add the missing opportunity_id attribute to the column in the Jobs table through the console, it does not show up even after I run a migration. Maybe I am doing that process wrong, but I have done it a few times now and have double checked to make sure I am doing it right. The migration file shows up under db/migrate but I can't figure out how to get it into the table.

Comment: You have to actually run the migration with `rake db:migrate`. But if you really have a Rails background you should know this - its absolute newbie stuff.

Comment: @max yes, I know. I ran db:migrate and if you read my previous comment it is not appearing after running db:migrate. And yes, I do come from a Rails background although I haven't worked on a project of this size for about a year in Rails. Plus, taking over someone else's project isn't exactly a walk in the park.

Comment: Can you add the migration which should add the column to your question? I can't see that the column is in `schema.rb`. Also try running `rake db:migrate:status`

Comment: Another thing that can throw you off is that if you are getting the error in RSpec you may have to run `rake db:test:prepare` as rails sometimes fails to keep the test db migrated.

Comment: @max thank you, I updated the schema.rb file. I added the opportunities table along with the jobs table, and I will run the test prepare and see if that helps. Thanks again for offering your help, I truly appreciate the help from seasoned developers

Comment: rails g migration AddOpportunityIdToJobs opportunity_id:integer <- thats what I ran in the terminal to add the column to the database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121287/discussion-between-kmaune-and-max).

Answer (score 0):

On line 2 of your view, it looks like you're expecting new jobs to already have an associated opportunity.

```
 <% title "New #{@job.opportunity.name} Job"%>
```

If this is the case, then the job routes should be nested under opportunities. So in `config/routes.rb`

```
 resources :opportunities do
   resources :jobs
 end
```

You can then create new jobs through `http://localhost:3000/opportunities/:id/jobs/new`

And in your JobsController:

```
 def new
   @opportunity = Opportunity.find(params[:opportunity_id])
   @job = Job.new(opportunity: @opportunity)
   # ...
```

Comment: I tried this, and I am getting a ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Opportunity without an ID) error. The error happened on this line of code: @opportunity = Opportunity.find(params[:opportunity_id])

Answer (score 0):

So when I look through your two table definitions I see that 1) there is no opportunity_id key in jobs and conversely, 2) no job_id key in opportunities. In order for your `has_many :opportunities` to work, you need to add a `job_id` field to the opportunities table. Here is a vastly simplified example of what I mean:

```
def Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :opportunities
end

def Opportunity < ActiveRecord::Base
end # shown for completeness of answer only
```

You will need to add the job_id foreign key to the opportunities table with a migration, for example:

```
class AddJobForeignKeyToOpportunities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :opportunities, :job_id, :integer
  end
end
```

If you're unsure how to deal with the migration, check out the Rails Guide for the [rails command-line tool](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html). Once you have that in place Rails will automagically give you access to the Opportunities associated with a Job as you might expect:

```
job = Job.first
job.opportunities
```

Keep in mind that you still won't be able to access `job.opportunity_id` as the error in your original question mentions. The many to one association you've set up requires that the Opportunity model have the foreign key. However, Rails will give you access to `job.opportunity_ids` plural.

[edit] To add an opportunity to a job you'll want to do something along the lines of:

```
opportunity = Opportunity.find(params[:opportunity_id])
job.opportunities << opportunity
```

You should always avoid referring to the foreign key directly on the associated model. Someone said this somewhere in another answer or comment here but I can't find it to credit them.

Instead rely on the Rails provided methods. In this example above, the `<<` operator is effectively setting job_id on the opportunity to link them up.